# Android: Possible to get a custom R.id

Tags: android

Is it possible to get android to give me a custom id?

so for example if I already have defined in xml:

```
R.id.some_layout
R.drawable.some_drawable
```

is there any function like this

```
R.custom_id("a_custom_id")
```

so I could then access as

```
R.id.a_custom_id
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can not dynamically create new IDs. Even if `R` was capable of doing so, you wouldn't be able to access it using `R.id.a_custom_id`. Java is not dynamic language, and cannot add fields at runtime.

---

There is, however, compile-time solution. In your `res/values/ids.xml` add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <item type="id" name="a_custom_id"/>
</resources>
```

And then you can reference `R.id.a_custom_id` in your code and `"@id/a_custom_id"` in xmls. Of course its still pre-defined id (as opposed to runtime-defined id).

Answer (score 1):

You can create  boolean, integer, dimension, color, and other array resources.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html