# Android: how to assign the custom identifiers to dynamic menu items?

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

There is problem.
In my app I have dynamicly built menu items in drawer menu.

```
    // data comes from database
    ArrayList<String> groupsName = mDbHelper.getAllGroupsName();

    Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
    SubMenu userGroupsLessonsMenu = m.addSubMenu(R.string.your_groups);

    for (String groupName : groupsName) {
      userGroupsLessonsMenu.add(groupName);
    };
```

OK, it works good. Now I want to react on click on these items. I would like to assign my custom identifier to menu items in order in

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
```

just to set this id to intent and start new activity.

I don't know if it's important, but hardcoded menu items have specific identifiers, and my menu items always have 0:

```
06-25 17:50:20.857 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 2131493021
06-25 17:50:35.210 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 2131493022
06-25 17:50:38.372 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 2131493023
06-25 17:50:41.410 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 2131493024
06-25 17:50:47.576 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 0
06-25 17:50:51.903 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 0
06-25 17:50:57.241 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 0
06-25 17:51:00.788 23358-23358/my.package.name W/id: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067182/6507689) to create custom IDs. Then, assign them with the function `setId`.

If the list is very dynamic, then You can just assign numbers. ID is just an `int`.